# Open RSS feed link in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

The following code is working but I want the links to open in a webview. How do I do that? I have created a webview activity called WebbVy.java but I'm guessing that I need to create an intent after the textview below that starts the webview activity. But how do I do that? At the moment, the textview is populated by title, pubdate, description and link (opens in browser) and I need the link to open in a webview instead of the browser.

**VisaHelaNyheten.java**

```
package se.sebastianliljegren.rss_feed;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VisaHelaNyheten extends Activity{
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.visa_hela_nyhet);

    String enNyhet = null;
    String mLink = null;


    final Intent bundleintent = getIntent();

    if (bundleintent != null)
    {
        Bundle b = bundleintent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE.VISA.SEN.INTENT");
        if (b == null)
        {
            enNyhet = "fel bundle?";
        }
        else
        {
            enNyhet = b.getString("title") + "\n\n" + b.getString("pubdate") + "\n\n" + b.getString("description") + "\n" + "\n\nMore information:\n" + b.getString("link");
            mLink = b.getString("link");

        }
    }
    else
    {
        enNyhet = "Information ej hittad.";
    }

    TextView db = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nyhet);
    db.setText(enNyhet);
    TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
    link.setText(mLink);

    link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(VisaHelaNyheten.this, WebbVy.class);
            intent.putExtra("LINK" mLink);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
        }
    }
```

**WebbVy.java**
    package se.sebastianliljegren.rss_feed;

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class WebbVy extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String link = intent.getStringExtra("link");

    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mainWebView.loadData(link, "text/html; charset=utf-8","utf-8");

}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview1" >

</WebView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate `TextView` to store the link like:

```
String enNyhet = null;
String mLink = null

enNyhet = b.getString("title") + "\n\n" + b.getString("pubdate") + "\n\n" + b.getString("description") + "\n";
mLink = b.getString("link");

TextView db = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nyhet);
db.setText(enNyhet);
TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
link.setText(mLink);
```

Now add a `onClickListener` to the link `TextView`:

```
link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Set the intent to your webview activity and put the string link as extra.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebbVy.class);
            intent.putExtra("LINK", mLink);
            startActivity(intent);                
        }
    });
```

Then in your webview activity you get the string from the intent and load it in the webview.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @margabro your code looks like exactly what I'm looking for! However, I'm getting two markers - syntax error on token "mLink" and "The Method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type intent is not applicable for the arguments (String)"?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. putExtra allows any of the normal variables like String, Integer, Long, Double, Boolean, etc... Try cleaning your project (Project > Clean) or delete all Intent imports and import them again... Let me know if it works...

Comment: Also try changing `Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebbVy.class);` with `Intent intent = new Intent(YOURACTIVITY.this, WebbVy.class);`

Comment: I cleared the project but still get those markers on putExtra and mLink. I already changed to `Intent intent = new Intent (VisaHelaNyheten.this, WebbVy.class);`

Comment: I don't really understand why you got that errors. Try also with bundles: `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("LINK", mLink); intent.putExtras(bundle); startActivity(intent);`

Comment: I edited my question above with the updated code as it is right now. Still get those markers on that line and I'm also unsure about my webview class, WebbVy.java. I don't get any errors on the code but I'm not sure if I've got it right?

Comment: This works
`final Bundle linkbundle = new Bundle(); linkbundle.putString("LINK", mLink);
  
  TextView db = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nyhet);
  db.setText(enNyhet);
  TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
  link.setText(mLink);
  
  link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(VisaHelaNyheten.this, WebbVy.class);
    intent.putExtras(linkbundle);
    startActivity(intent);`

But now there are two links instead of one in the view and both opens with the browser and not the webview?

Comment: Post the webview class and layout please!

Comment: the webview class is WebbVy.java and the layout is webview.xml. I don't understand why to isolate the link and put it in a separate textview? That just makes the link appear twice, doesn't it?

Comment: I posted them above in my edited question. The change I've made to VisaHelaNyheten.java that isn't edited is the use of bundle according to your comment.

Comment: I forgot to delete the link from the first `TextView`. Do you have on the link TextView (in the layout) set the value `android:autoLink="web"`?? If so, remove it because it is overwriting the click listener and it will always redirect you to the browser.

Comment: Yes, the textview in the layout has the value set to android:autoLink="web". I removed it and ran the application but when I did, the link was no longer a link, only text, and when I clicked it, it just said "null".

Comment: Oh gosh... this is getting harder. Just upload your project in Dropbox or somewhere and I will take a look.

Comment: Your help is highly appreciated! I have uploaded the project to my web server: http://www.sebastianliljegren.se/RSS-feed.zip

Comment: Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lv7pqolfhk4oo6m/RSS-feed.rar
You don't need to use custom webview client. loadURL does it right.

Comment: Please, if my solution worked and you are happy with my help I will much appreciate if you accept my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I'll check it out as soon as I'm back on my laptop! Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Wow! Now it does exactly what it should! Your help is much appreciated! Gonna study the code thoroughly now and learn from your changes!